# Azure API Management - Additional fields during signup process

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We would like to know more about our users registered in our Azure API Management portal such as what company they represent.

Azure API Management provides functionality to keep track of API users. Users can register an account from where they can subscribe to different products etc. During the registration process some information is gathered from a form such as firstname and lastname.

From what we've seen, these fields are mapped to the user tab under the API Management resource in the Azure portal. We cannot, however, find a way to add additional fields to the users or the signup form.

The ideal result would be to add an additional field like 'Company' which would also be added to the signup process. Is it possible?

Comment: Just try this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c

Comment: @MohamedInfaaz, you should add this as an answer, since at the moment this is the only way to resolve the issue.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin Okay ... Thanks

Comment: @MohamedInfaaz many thanks for the info! We already have a lot of users authorized directly through the API Management portal. I'm unsure if we want to introduce additional signup-flow at the moment (the AD solution) but I'm grateful to know this is the option we have.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin thanks for clarifying this currently is the solution available.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this document, in Azure AD B2C you can create custom signup policy. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c
defining custom attribute on Azure AD B2C,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#use-a-custom-attribute-in-your-sign-up-policy
at this time, custom attributes do not show up in the Azure portal's Users & Groups blade. As an admin, you can only view and update those [using the Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#use-custom-attributes).